# Importação de base SQL para Azure

Tags: sql-server, microsoft-azure

Possuo um banco de dados no SQL Server 2008 R2 com um tamanho de 65GB, e possuo ele em .BAK também.
Existe a possibilidade em importar esse banco de dados para minha conta do azure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sim, é possível e pode ser feita de diversas formas.

Uma delas é usar o [SQL Database Migration Wizard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj156144.aspx). Esse [artigo do MSDN<sup>en</sup>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee730904.aspx) mostra algumas outras formas possíveis de migração.

Note que para o seu volume de dados, é interessante ter uma boa conexão com a internet.

Comment: Não conhecia essa ferramente, mas analisando, é bem simples de usar. Obrigado pela resposta.